# How to aggregate data by transect with dplyr in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

I have a large database which I want to simplify by grouping observations into transects. I have used the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
AGGDATA<-DATA %>%  
  select(Habitat,Transect,Number,Abundance) %>%
  group_by(Transect) %>%
  mutate(TotalNum = sum(Number),TotalAbund = sum(Abundance))
```

Sample output for `DATA$Abundance` looks like this:

```
  [1]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 [24]   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16   9   6   1   21   5
 [47]  83  32  10   1  24   2  16  85   7   4   0  21   1   7   7   9   4  76   0   1   2   2   1
 [70]   9   2   0   3   6  41   4   3   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
 [93]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  78  14   3   1  10  44   5   0   2   2  31   1   3  18
```

And sample output for `AGGDATA$TotalAbund` looks like this:

```
[1]     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[19]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[37]    1    1    1    1  351  351  351  351  351  351  351  351  351  351  351  351  351   351
[55]  351  351  351  351  351  351  175  175  175  175  175  175  175  175  175  175  175   175
[73]  175  175  175  175  175  175  175  175    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

The code has summed `DATA$Abundance` values for each transect. However, I would like one value per transect rather than one value repeated for each transect observation. I'm still new to this so I hope that makes sense.

Can anyone help? Thanks!!

Comment: Try `summarise` instead of `mutate`

Comment: Great, this worked! Do you happen to know how to summarise a factor? I want to include habitat which is the same value across each transect? Thanks so much!!

Comment: You could simply get the first value of habitat per transect, for example: `... summarise(TotalNum = sum(Number), TotalAbund = sum(Abundance), habitat = habitat[1])`

Comment: It worked a treat, thanks - you're a saviour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use data.table library. It is much faster. In case of you didn't provide a data set, so your solution can look like

```
library(data.table)
DATA <- data.table(DATA)
AGGDATA <- DATA[, .(TotalNum = sum(Number),TotalAbund = sum(Abundance)), by = Transect]
```